# Как поменять цвет фона

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы на белом фоном были все восемь картинок одновременно, а не каждая по отдельности?

HTML код:

```
<div id="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                        <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/11.jpg" alt="">
                        The Arecaceae are a botanical family of perennial climbers, shrubs, acaules and trees commonly known as palm trees
                        </div></a>
                        <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/22.jpg" alt="">
                        Palms are among the best known and most extensively cultivated plant families. They have been important to humans throughout much of history.</div></a>
                        <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/33.jpg" alt="">
                        Many common products and foods are derived from palms, and palms are also widely used in landscaping, making them one of the most economically important plants.</div></a>
                        <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/44.jpg" alt="">
                        In many historical cultures, palms were symbols for such ideas as victory, peace, and fertility. For inhabitants of cooler climates today, palms symbolize the tropics and vacations.</div></a>
                        <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/55.jpg" alt="">
                        Whether as shrubs, trees, or vines, palms have two methods of growth: solitary or clustered. The common representation is that of a solitary shoot ending in a crown of leaves.</div></a>
                        <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/66.jpg" alt="">
                        Most palms grow in the tropics and subtropics. They are abundant throughout the tropics and subtropics, and thrive in almost every habitat they are in. Their diversity is highest in wet, lowland forests, especially in ecological "hotspots" such as Madagascar, which has more endemic palms than all of Africa.</div></a>
                        <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/77.jpg" alt="">
                        Subfamily Calamoideae includes the climbing palms, such as rattans. The leaves are usually pinnate; derived characters (synapomorphies) include spines on various organs, organs specialized for climbing, an extension of the main stem of the leaf-bearing reflexed spines, and overlapping scales covering the fruit and ovary.</div></a>
                        <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/88.jpg" alt="">
                        This monopodial character may be exhibited by prostrate, trunkless, and trunk-forming members.</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Если поменять цвет `row` на белый и убрать `thumbnail`, то получается такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сверху и снизу выглядит не очень. Тогда нужно в CSS играться с `margin-top`, `margin-bottom` у класса `row`?

Comment: `то получается такое` - получается ровно то, что заказывали.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. все получилось как хотел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать белым фон у блока `<div class="row">`.

Comment: И тогда нужно будет убрать класс thumbnail?

Comment: Насколько я вижу, нет. Но вообще, я бы советовал выложить более полный код в ваш вопрос, так как пока не слишком понятно, откуда у вас берется серый фон, к примеру.

Comment: серый фон прописал в css как body {
 background-color: #ececec;
}

Comment: @Ravdan, понятно. Ну вроде вы уже разобрались с тем, что нужно было сделать )

Comment: Да. Спасибо, что помогли.